# How to copy cells from one sheet to another based on criteria without getting error 'Exception: You do not have permission to call setValues'

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I am attempting to copy some row values from Sheet1 to Sheet2 based on a criteria and a cell value where some rows are only copied when `[Qualification] = 'Qualified'` and, if `[No of positions] = 1` then the values are copied once, if `[No of positions] = 2` then the values are copied twice.

Below is an example.

**Sheet1**

| Lead Type | Lead ID | Company Name | Employment Type | No of positions | Qualification |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| External | B21 | KidRed Co. | Full Time | 1 | Not Qualified |
| Africa | B24 | Freddie Co. | Part Time | 2 | Qualified |
| Base | B35 | Akila Co. | Full Time | 1 | Qualified |
| External | B40 | SeeQue Co. | Part Time | 1 | Not Qualified |

**Sheet2**

| Lead ID | Company Name | Qualification |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B24 | Freddie Co. | Qualified |
| B24 | Freddie Co. | Qualified |
| B35 | Akila Co. | Qualified |

I am currently running this query

```
function myFunction() {
  const srcSheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the source sheet name.
  const dstSheetName = "Sheet2"; // Please set the destination sheet name.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const [srcSheet, dstSheet] = [srcSheetName, dstSheetName].map(s => ss.getSheetByName(s));
  const [, ...v] = srcSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  const values = v.flatMap(([, b, c, , e, f]) => e > 0 && f == "Qualified" ? [...Array(e)].fill([b, c, f]) : [])
dstSheet.getRange(dstSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

in the App Script and calling `myFunction()` in 'Sheet2' cell [A2]  yet it returns this error:

> Exception: You do not have permission to call setValues (line 515)

Comment: About `@tanaike See above.`, from your showing error of `Exception: You do not have permission to call setValues `, how do you run your script? If you are using `myFunction()` as a custom function, I think that such an error occurs. So, when you run the script with the script editor instead of the custom function, is that your expected result?

Comment: As a simple method for executing the script with the script editor, how about [this official document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone#running_a_standalone_script)? And also, when I tested your showing script using your sample input tables of "Sheet1" and "Sheet2" by executing `myFunction` with the script editor, I thought that your goal might be able to be achieved. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike, yes I was running as a function. How should I go about it? I don't understand.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `yes I was running as a function. How should I go about it? I don't understand.`, in your situation, please run your script with the script editor. Please select the function name from the right side of "Debug". And, please click "Run" button. By this, the script is run. When a dialog of authorization is opened, please permit the scopes. By this, the script is run. Also, you can see [this official document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone#running_a_standalone_script).

Comment: And also, I thought that this post will be useful for understanding how to run Google Apps Script with the script editor. https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-beginner-guide/

Comment: How do I retain the index of the row with the other query instead `const SAMPLE = v => v.flatMap(([, b, c, , e, f]) => e > 0 ? [...Array(e)].fill([b, c, f]) : []);`

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have thought that you wanted to run your script with the script editor from your question. But, from your reply, it seems that my understanding was not correct. It seems that you wanted to run your script with the custom function. I apologize for my poor English skill. And, now, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer. And, I have to study English more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) should preferably get their values through formula parameters. The values they return get placed in the formula cell, and down and to the right from there.

You can convert your function to a proper custom function like this:

```
/**
* Filters rows by matching the sixth column against criterion, and repeats
* each matching row as many times as specified in the fifth column.
*
* @param {Sheet1!A2:F} values The rows to filter and repeat.
* @param {"Qualified"} criterion The value to match to the sixth column in values.
* @return {Object[][]} The processed values.
* @customfunction
*/
function RepeatMatching(values, criterion = 'Qualified') {
  return values.flatMap(([, b, c, , e, f]) =>
    e > 0 && f == criterion ? [...Array(e)].fill([b, c, f]) : []
  );
}
```

To test the function, choose **Insert > Sheet** and put this formula in cell `A2` of the new sheet:

`=RepeatMatching(Sheet1!A1:F, "Qualified")`

Comment: Thank you @doubleunary, but I don't understand how to define the param or the return. Kindly assist.

Comment: Edited the answer to include instructions how to test the custom function.

Comment: Oh I understand now. My bad.  One other caveat, in the case that No.of Positions that have already been copied to Sheet2 changes from 2 to 1, cells are shifted up. I would like instead for the entire row to be deleted. Would you know how to solve that?

Comment: same thing happens when No. of Positions increases, the cells shift down. This creates a mismatch adjacent columns are filled with information. What i'd envision is that a new row is created below already existing ones.

Comment: That cannot be done with spreadsheet formulas or custom functions. You should follow Tanaike's advice and call the function through some other means, such as a [button](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets), a [custom menu item](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus), a [sidebar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars) or a [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers).

Comment: Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). When you post a new question, please describe the _problem_ you are trying to solve rather than asking for improvements to a possible _solution_ you think would work. See [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)